# Moment.js show warning for future date of 1 day and error for days >1

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to display errors and warnings:

- Future Date of 1 Day should be warning
- Future date of > 1 days should be error

```
// date can be different (i.e 10-08-2020)
const date = data[attr]
if (date.isAfter(moment().endOf('day'))) {
        return "This should be an error;
    }

    if (moment().add('days', 1)) {
        return 'This should be a warning';
    }
```

I think I used wrong methods and I was unable to achieve what I want.

Comment: Do you mean if some date is greater than today it should be a warning? If so where is that date in your code?

Comment: if date is tomorrow, should be a warning else if date is > tomorrow should be error.

Comment: Again: Where is that date in your code? You need to compare a date with tomorrow. You can't compare nothing with tomorrow, can you?

Comment: I updated the question. The date can be like this. data[attr] can be i.e 10-08-2020, in this case if tomorrow is 11.08.2020 then should be a warning, else if is more than 11.08.2020 should be error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [date_diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) moment function to determine the `date passed` and the `current date`.

If the date passed to the function is `tomorrow` then it will show a warning - If the date is `2` days ahead of today then it will show an error message.

Also, As you may see i am using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which is short form of `if` and `else`- this way we can *reduce the line of code* we write and have the same results.

**Live Demo:** (I have also added comments for you as well to detail every line of code)

```js
//This is just to for purpose to show the all dates are working
let dataAttrToday = moment().endOf('day') //Todays date
let dataAttr1Days = moment('11-08-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY').endOf('day') //1 day ahead
let dataAttr2Days = moment('12-08-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY').endOf('day') //2 days ahead
let dataAttr3Days = moment('13-08-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY').endOf('day') //3 days ahead

//get dats difference and return message
function checkDays(date) {
  let getDiff = moment().diff(date, 'days') //get difference
  return (getDiff == 0) ? "This is today" : (getDiff == -1) ? "This is an warning" : (getDiff == -2) ? "This is an error" : 'This is an error'
}

console.log("10-08-2020 " + checkDays(dataAttrToday)) //This is today
console.log("11-08-2020 " + checkDays(dataAttr1Days)) //this is a warning
console.log("12-08-2020 " + checkDays(dataAttr2Days)) //this is an error
console.log("13-08-2020 " + checkDays(dataAttr2Days)) //this is an error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think "today", "tomorrow" and the day after tomorrow shouldn't be hard coded. But apart from that your solution is very good.

Comment: Thanks you! OP will be passing an actual to the function `checkDays()` - Hard coded date are just an example and for purpose of this answer to show that its working.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes this solution is very nice. Just I'm wondering, if I select today date from date picker (10-08-2020) then the warning start showing from dt 13-08-2020 and the error from 14-08-2020

Comment: @alar Sorry i did not get you ? you mean you are getting a warning message it date 13-04 and 14-08 ?

Comment: it means I'm getting warning message after tomorrow and not tomorrow. and also I'm getting error message only for one day.

Comment: @alar I have edited my ansswer to show the that all dates including `12-08-2020` will show an error message AND `11-08-2020` will show only warning message.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "11-08-2020"; //input date read from somewhere

var today     = moment().format("YYYYMMDD");

var tomorrow  = moment().add(1, 'days').format("YYYYMMDD");

var inputDate = moment(date, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYYMMDD");

if ( inputDate > tomorrow ) {
    alert ("error");
} else if ( inputDate > today ) {
    alert ("warning")
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yf95k8eg/